# Custom Merkle Patricia Tree

Tags: state-trie, merkle-patricia-tries, state-trie-pruning

One of the requirements of building our company's DApp is to maintain a separate, custom Merkle Patricia Tree that contain's data from our company's platform only. The Tree needs all CRUD operations for each ethereum accounts, and must be saved across the ethereum network. So basically I need a State trie equivalent of Ethereum but only with our custom data. Can anyone give me hints on how to do this or reference to where I can start?